# Django signup neither gives error message nor registering user

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views, django-authentication

I am beginner to python Django. I got stuck at signup form. I have created a form using signupform, but when I am submitting the form its not register the user or  not get any error.
When i code it first time it works perfectly but when I open next day to move forward in my learning but it's working like last time.

**model.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.
class AppUser(User):
    pass
```

**form.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, get_user_model
from stock.models import AppUser


class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput)
    password  = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = AppUser
        fields = ('username', 'password1', 'password2' )
```

**htmlTemplate**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<div>
  <h2>Sign Up</h2>
  <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Signup</button>
  </form>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

**views.py**

```
class SignupView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'stock/signup.html'

    def get(self, request):
        form = SignUpForm()
        args = {'form':form}

        return render(request, self.template_name, args)


    def post(self, request):
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            form = SignUpForm()
            return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form, 'error':'Username/Password already exist or password should be match' })
```

Comment: To see errors, you should remove the `form = SignUpForm()` from the else-block. Pass the form you have which has been validated and contains the errors. Btw, did you set the `AUTH_USER_MODEL` setting and are you subclassing `User` on purpose? Usually you'd subclass `AbstractUser`.

Comment: Remove the `form = SignupForm()` in the `post` method. Then you can see what is wrong.

Comment: Thank you guys its working now...kindly can you guide me how to display different validations error like Password not match etc..

Comment: Consider using [django-registration](https://django-registration.readthedocs.io/)!